# Is a CSRF token needed for "AJAX"-only "application/json"-only POSTs?

Tags: ajax, forms, security, xmlhttprequest, csrf

If I understand correctly, there's no need for a CSRF token if you're only allowing JSON as `application/json` from an "AJAX" (really AJAJ for JSON) form, right?

If someone tries to post to the form from another page using some nifty POST-to-iFrame hack it will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can throw it out immediately.

If someone tries to post to the form using AJAJ, it will only succeed if OPTIONS has the CORS headers that allow it.

Conclusion: unless you're using CORS you're safe from CSRF as when you're using `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Any contradictions I'm not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Sec.SE question and answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10227/csrf-with-json-post). In short: you are correct (presently), but it's probably not a good idea to rely on this behavior, so use tokens anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Update

So much has changed - such as `fetch` giving more control to requests.

### Yes, it's still dangerous

It *is* possible to do a cross-site JSON POST that includes cookies.

(the attacker can't see the response, but they *can* POST successfully)

CSRF is necessary *by default*.

### Yes, it's easy to mitigate

#### Same-Site Cookies

There's now a [`same-site` cookie option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite). Using this *correctly* makes it completely unnecessary to use CSRF tokens at all.

#### API Tokens

Completely abandoning Cookies in favor of per-request API tokens, such as the well-standardized `JWT`, will make CSRF attacks impossible.

This is best done by separating token routes from cookie routes, such as:

- `/api/account/xxxx` for authenticated JSON API
- `/api/assets/xxxx` for `<img src="xxxx" />` and other assets that should not have a token in the URL and must therefore rely on cookies

Comment: There's one case where same-site cookies may not protect you, which is a bit more common than you might expect: if you allow other services to be hosted on subdomains of your site, e.g. helpdesk.mydomain.com - and you're worried that those third party vendors may have security flaws of their own. More notes on that here: https://simonwillison.net/2021/Aug/3/samesite/#consider-subdomains