# How to ensure continuous CSRF token validation for all AJAX requests in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4, csrf-token

Her I have created login form and with csrf token If i send first request it will validate properly. Now I tried with wrong passwod than new csrf token is received from server. And When Again i will resend request with correct password it will show error 403.

Here is my code.
1 . View File

```
<form action="<?=$module."/validate_login"?>" id="form" name="form">
                        <input type="hidden" class="txt_csrfname" name="<?= csrf_token() ?>" value="<?= csrf_hash() ?>" />
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <label class="mb-1 text-dark">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control" id="username" name="username"
                                placeholder="hello@example.com">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4 position-relative">
                            <label class="mb-1 text-dark">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="dz-password" name="password" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Password">
                            <span class="show-pass eye">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                            </span>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-between mt-4 mb-2">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-check custom-checkbox mb-3">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customCheckBox1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="customCheckBox1">Remember my
                                        preference</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <a href="<?=base_url("forgot-password")?>" class="btn-link text-primary">Forgot
                                    Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="text-center mb-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row" id="alert-message" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"
                                    aria-label="btn-close"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></span>
                                </button>
                                <strong>Error!</strong> In-valid username or password.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

2 . JS FILE

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules : {
        username : 'required',
        password : 'required'
    },
    messages : {
        username : 'Please enter e-mail',
        password : 'Please enter password'
    },
    submitHandler : function(form,e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var form_data = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            url  : SITE_URL+"validate-login",
            type : "POST",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            data : form_data,
            beforeSend : function(){

            },
            success : function(response){
                $('.txt_csrfname').val(response.data.token);
                if(response.success == "1"){
                    $("#alert-message").css("display","none");  
                    window.location.href= SITE_URL+"Dashboard";                      
                }else{
                    console.log(response.data.token);
                    $("#alert-message").css("display","");
                }
            },
            error : function(){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

3. Controller

   public function validate_login(){

   ```
    $request = service('request');
    $requestArr = $request->getPost();
    $responseArr = array("success"=>"1","data"=>array(),"message"=>"");
    $data = array();
    $data['token'] = csrf_hash();
    $ipaddress = $this->request->getIPAddress();


    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|valid_email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

   if($this->validate($rules)){
        $userArr = $this->Auth->login($requestArr['username']);    
        if(!empty($userArr)) {
            $verify_password = password_verify($requestArr['password'],$userArr->password);
            if($verify_password){
                $responseArr['success'] = "1"; 
                $responseArr['message'] = "Loged in successfully.";

                $this->session->set([                        
                    'tbl_users_id'=>$userArr->tbl_users_id,
                    'full_name'=>$userArr->full_name,
                    'username'=>$userArr->username,
                    'email'=>$userArr->email
                ]);

                $logArr = array(
                    'user_id' => $userArr->tbl_users_id,
                    'module' => $this->module,
                    'module_id' => $userArr->tbl_users_id,
                    'action' => "LOGIN",
                    'ip_address' => $ipaddress,
                    'remarks' => "User Loged In",
                    'raw_data'=> ""
                );

                insert_log($logArr);
            }else{
                $responseArr['success'] = "0";
                $responseArr['message'] = "In-valid username or password.";
            }
        }else{
            $responseArr['success'] = "0";
            $responseArr['message'] = "In-valid username or password.";
        }   
    }else{
        $responseArr['message']= "Required Fields are missing";
    }

    $responseArr['data']= $data;
    output($responseArr);
   ```

   }

It will validate CSRF Token only first call.
After that it will show 403 error.
Want to validate csrf token with all ajax request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter CSRF valid for only one time ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502548/codeigniter-csrf-valid-for-only-one-time-ajax-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's most likely that you've set [`\app\Config\Security::$regenerate`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/app/Config/Security.php#L74C17-L74C28) to `true`.

##### Excerpt from [`\app\Config\Security`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/app/Config/Security.php#L74C17-L74C28)

```php
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CSRF Regenerate
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Regenerate CSRF Token on every submission.
     */
    public bool $regenerate = true;
```

This setting would regenerate the token for every `['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH']` HTTP request.

In addition, in your Javascript source code, you tend to update the token: `$('.txt_csrfname').val(response.data.token);` in your AJAX success handler yet your Controller method `validate_login()` **doesn't** provide/send such information. Another issue I would raise is, what if it's not successful? Your AJAX error handler is empty, resulting in a token mismatch on the next POST HTTP request since you didn't update your front-end CSRF token on error.

##### Solution 1:

Disable `\app\Config\Security::$regenerate`.

```php
 public bool $regenerate = false;
```

Then, you **won't** have to update your CSRF token on every `POST` HTTP request (`$('.txt_csrfname').val(response.data.token);`).

##### Solution 2:

Enable `\app\Config\Security::$regenerate` and design an efficient mechanism to update your front-end CSRF token on every `['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH']` HTTP request. And the front-end CSRF token update **must** happen whether the request is successful or not.
I provided such a solution in a question I answered previously. [codeigniter4 code to add employee redirects to itself on submit when regenerate is set to true in config.security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620955/7376590)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you use ajax for your form submission, you can send your data as JSON, or set any custom header for your request. Then you don't need to worry about any CSFR.

Also have a look at axios library, which can do both.

But rather confirm with someone with a better security knowledge.

Comment: This is incorrect - you need a CSRF token for AJAX POST requests, just as with any other POST request.  The format of the data in your POST is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you really sure? Look at this presentation: https://youtu.be/kEYYDWQPa0w?si=FW0kNZRl_86TXn89&t=894

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  There are a few other questions here that discuss it (eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/9089909/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73639169/6089612, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/58755/234861) but probably the strongest indicator is that the OWASP site describes that is is required: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#javascript-guidance-for-auto-inclusion-of-csrf-tokens-as-an-ajax-request-header.

Comment: Well now, reading the posts, I'm even more sure, that you are not correct. As one of the accepted answer states: "It's not possible to get a POSTed <form> to submit a request with Content-Type: application/json." Also a better idea is to use a API token for example JWT token. (Which is essentially setting a custom header of the request).

Comment: @Dusan Your assumption is wrong. Once you enable the `csrf` filter, the CodeIgniter framework will look for the CSRF token either in your [`X-CSRF-TOKEN` header](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/app/Config/Security.php#L45) ...

Comment: @Dusan ...  or the [`tokenName`'s key-value](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/app/Config/Security.php#L36C33-L36C47) of your  [`['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH']` request body](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/system/Security/Security.php#L282). If it's [invalid or null, an exception](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/eb1d5e05a725f1634b15eda85a058d92046941cc/system/Security/Security.php#L297) will be thrown.